# mysql MYSQL SQL Как добавить id категории к уже имеющимся id в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть, например, запись в таблице с полем категории со значением 5,12,19. Как к этой записи добавить категорию  со значением 17 так что бы получилось 5,12,19,17?

Прокатит такой вариант?

```
UPDATE dle_post SET category=category+'17' WHERE id=$id;
```

И потом другой вопрос как удалить категорию с со значением 17 что бы категории со значением 5,12,19 остались?

Comment: Не надо хранить никакие значения через запятую. SQL не предназначен для работы с такими значениями. Это нарушает первую нормальную форму (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Конечно вы можете так делать, но время разработки программы вырастет раз в 5 по сравнению с нормальным хранением. Сложность возрастет, количество глюков будет огромным. Посему, настоятельно рекомендую создать отдельную таблицу связи где каждое значение будет в отдельной строке

Comment: А строки в mysql объединяются не оператором `+`, а функцией `concat()`. Удаление значения из строки я даже представлять не хочу, наверняка это можно сделать, но запрос будет строк 10, только ради этого...

Comment: Это таблица движка dle мне просто нужно при определеных действия добавить категорию, а потом через время ее удалить.

Comment: Лучше делайте это на стороне php, проще выйдет. И что то мне подсказывает, что раз движок так хранит, то у него должны быть готовые функции для манипуляции этим ... Удалять в принципе с помощью `replace()` можно попробовать. только там наверняка надо будет отдельно рассмотреть варианты "в начале строки" и "не в начале"

Comment: Я уже думал что бы сделать выборку с базы и поле категории занести в переиенную php. Потом сделать update с подставлением переменой и моего значения.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел как это реализуется:

```
UPDATE dle_post SET category = CONCAT(category,',17')
```